# When should I use layout_centerHorizontal=true and gravity="center_horizonatal" and foregroundGravity="centerHorizontal"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gravity

I read the documentation, but I am not able get when should I use which?

Comment: If you google it you can find it !!

Comment: No. I cannot. Google is banned in my campus internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use **RelativeLayout** - You should use **layout_centerHorizontal,layout_centerVertical,layout_centerInParent**

but when you use **LinearLayout** , you should use gravity to align children i.e., **layout_gravity and gravity**.

**foregroundGravity** is used with **foreground** tag.
What is in foreground it will align according to foregroundGravity